# How to add a forgot password feature for the described system without compromising its security?

Tags: security, encryption, passwords, reset-password

I created a security system that uses the users password to encrypt the users private key which is then stored on the database. So a user can only retrieve the private key if he enters the correct password which is then used to decrypt the private key stored on the database.

This system has some admirable security features but has the flaw that it is hard to do a 'forgotten password' option. The only way I could imagine is by storing a copy of all private keys somewhere else and encrypt them with a master server password and when a user forgets his password the server allows him to re encrypt his private key with the new password.

The problem with this method is that if the master server password where somehow compromised all account information would also be compromised with it. Is there a way of adding a reset password method without having to change the system to much or compromising its security?

Comment: Do not support password recovery, that is a huge snake pit. For starters how will you verify the user securely? Then there is the security of the saved private keys, that is a huge attraction for attackers, expect the attacker to gain admin access to the server.

Comment: @zaph - I'm not sure the OP is talking about password recovery, as opposed to a password reset, etc.

Comment: yes, sorry if I worded that wrong, I do mean reset. Password recovery is both bad practice and I don't store my users password so I couldn't do it XD

Comment: And just for future reference, what does OP mean ?

Comment: Do you want to recover the private keys?

Comment: "Original post/poster".

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth Note the question states: "storing a copy of all private keys".

Comment: I only said the "storing a copy of all private keys" as a bad example of what I'm trying to avoid. Thats why I said "The only way I could think of doing it"

Comment: Let's try re-stating the intention. A user has a private key and it is encrypted with his password. If a user forgets the password he can replace it with a new password and again have access to the private key. In order to do this either the private key or password must be saved. But passwords should not be saved, only password verifiers so that leaves maintaining a copy of the private key which is escrowing. Is this correct? But this becomes a huge liability and attraction for attackers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you escrow the private keys you need to have them on another server that is not directly connected to the Internet. Then rate limit and alarm all accesses to the escrowed keys. Also consider an [HSM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hardware_security_module).

Comment: I don't know what an escrow is, but I think the separate server idea could work if there is no other way

Comment: Here I mean another party maintaing a copy of encryption keys, you are the other party.

Comment: This is the best solution I can see, so I might have to redesighn the system itselfe to allow for the forgot password to work. I will update If I figure out a good solution